# Strange problem with imports in Java Application

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm building a plugin to extend the Eclipse BPEL Designer. That plugin is supposed to allow users to add meta information to certain model elements via EAnnotations. I already did the same thing for a BPMN model and it work just finde but when doing this for the BPEL designer I reveive rather strange exceptions. 
The first I thing realized when trying to extend the BPEL Designer was that the designers plugins are defined in an unusual package structure. Instead of org.eclipse.bpel.xxx they have a "bin" in front of all package names. When I'm trying to import some of the designers classes I therefore have to refernce the bin path to make it work. However all the examples I was able to find just imported classes from the ordinary package structure.

Most of the time importing classes with the bin in front of the package name worked fine for me but every now and then I receive a strange error message. The message is in the form of: The type org.eclipse.bpel.xxx cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files 
It seems that Eclipse somehow can't find certain classes. I'm stuck at this point for over a week now and don't find any solution. From my point of view the problem has to be seen in the BPEL Designer plugins. Inside those plugins they reference classes in the form of org.eclipse.bpel.xxx but as I said when I reference those plugins their classes are inside packages with a "bin" in front of the normal package name. Could that be an explanation why certain classes can't be referenced by Eclipse and I get those strange error messages?

I'd appreciate any new ideas about that problem and hope that somwebody can give me an advice to solve that problem.

Cheers
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

I already encountered in the past such troubles ...

I think there is a problem with the export/import of the BPEL Designer plugin.

How did you get this plugin ? Are you working with binary plugin or plugin imported as source in your SDk ?

Try to get again this plugin, may be an other version, or from an other source .. an update site.

I really think these "bin" packages/folders should not be here

Hope this can help ...

Comment: Hi Manuel. Thanks for the quick reply. I got the plugin from the official BPEL Designer update site. I reference those plugins in the required plugin section in my plugin.xml.

Comment: Hi,

I downloaded BPEL from official web site and I am encountering the same problem you described. I really think there had been a problem when they exported their UI plugin. if you look at the manifest file of org.eclipse.bpel.ui plug-in you can see that org.eclipse.bpel.ui.* packages are exported and not bin.org.eclipse.bpel.ui.*.

We had the same problem a while ago with our plugins and i am almost sure it was an export problem.

I think you should report the problem http://www.eclipse.org/bpel/developers.php)

You can also try to checkout the designer sources, the problem should goes away